# Get the .html after the echo

Tags: php

How to get the link of `.html` after the `.$obj->product_name.` ?

I have tried it as bellow. But it only shows the link of `http://.com/forbiden` insted of `http://.com/forbiden rice.html` where it cuts the `rice.html`

```
        echo '<span class="product-name"><a href=products/'.$obj->product_name ."html". 'target=_blank>'.$obj->product_name.'</a></span></br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `urlencode($obj->product_name)`
Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi,sir thanks. Do you mean like this? `echo '<span class="product-name"><a href=products/'.$obj->product_name ."html". 'target=_blank>'.urlencode($obj->product_name).'</a></span></br>';`

Comment: like this: echo '<span class="product-name"><a href=products/'.urlencode($obj->product_name) ."html". 'target=_blank>'. $obj->product_name . '</a></span></br>';

Answer (score 0):

Attribute values containing spaces must be quoted in HTML (and it is good practise to always quote your attribute values).

The space between forbiden and rice is terminating the attribute value.

URLs aren't allowed to have spaces in them anyway, so you should run the string through `urlencode` too.

You'll find it easier to deal with the quotes if you break out of PHP mode to output HTML instead of trying to mash it together in strings.

Also note that you should escape text content for HTML with `htmlspecialchars` as a defence against XSS.

```
$url = "products/" .urlencode($obj->product_name) . ".html";
?>
    <span class="product-name">
        <a 
            href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($url); ?>" 
            target="_blank">
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($obj->product_name); ?>
        </a>
    </span>
    <br>
```